# Regarding MySQL deployed on GCP load

Tags: mysql, performance, yii2, google-cloud-platform, load

I am almost done building a website that I target to have 10,000 users. It's free, so I'd like to keep the cost as low as possible.

All but two tables are less than 100,000 rows (read only). Off the remaining, one table will have about 5,200 rows per user in total and nothing less. The other I estimate about 1.5mn rows per user over two years, assuming they continue using it that long.

The latter table is as follows, and the former is the same except for col3...

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col2` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col3` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk1_ix` (`col1`),
  KEY `fk2_ix` (`col2`),
  KEY `fk3_ix` (`col3`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`col1`) REFERENCES `pktbl1` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`col2`) REFERENCES `pktbl2` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk3` FOREIGN KEY (`col3`) REFERENCES `pktbl3` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Both the tables will on average be written to about 10-20 times a day, and read about 4-5 times, for every active user.

I'd like to estimate my running cost and have two primary questions and appreciate any other inputs.

1) Will MySQL reasonably be able to handle my load.

2) How much CPU / RAM do you reckon I'd need to handle my load with a response time / lag of up to one second.

My website is designed using PHP Yii2 framework, so I can just switch databases, if required. The queries are simple inserts and indexed select statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 Billion rows, mostly in small tables?  That sounds like 1 terabyte of disk space.  Plan for that.

200K queries (write or read) per day?  That's only a few per second.  No problem on any server.  This assumes, however, that the queries are not too complex.

Will MySQL handle it?  Look around in this forum (better yet, dba.stackoverflow), you will see much bigger systems being discussed.

CPU -- Usually the least of the problems.

RAM -- Depends on the queries.  These days, I would not start with anything less than 4GB.

Cloud -- It's a viable option.  You pay extra, but have fewer hassles, especially if you need to upgrade.

Get 100 users on the system, then take stock of what you have.  See what the numbers look like.

If you ever get into performance problems, *first* look at the queries and indexes to see if the slowest query can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to estimate, your requirements are very low. If you are able to do some load testing that will help you.

However if you can tolerate a few minutes downtime, you are able to scale your Cloud SQL instance up or down. This might give you confidence that starting on an `f1-micro` or `g1-small` does not prevent you from upgrading should performance not meet your needs.

Comment: GCP is much more flexible in scaling the instance than AWS, but if some one has experience with GCP and says, X instance would be required, then I can estimate my annual cost.

Comment: If you multiply the numbers together, this is a lot of data. MySQL on f1-micro or g1-small will constantly hit this disks due to no memory for caching and performance will be poor to unusable. The only real answer is to create a real-world simulation and benchmark.